# Доверять сертификатам nginx

Tags: nginx, websphere

В nginx есть два сертификата .pem и .key куда их добавить в WebSphere application server чтобы он доверял им.

Answer (score 0):

Вот https://habrahabr.ru/post/252821/  Правда по этой инструкции чуть рейтинг понизили до просто A

Comment: Добавить нужно свои сертификаты. которые уже есть. Теперь надо чтобы websphre application server доверял этим сертификатам